# The Date becomes one day behind after passing from Angular 9 to Web API of ASP.NET Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

The date becomes one day behind after passing from Angular 9 to Web API of ASP.NET Core. From angular the date is passing correctly
from angular passing it as "Thu Jul 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" but when it comes on api call it becomes "29-07-2020 18:30:00"

Answer (score 2):

These dates are equal, the 1st one is inclusive timezone shift, the 2nd one is UTC.
You have to construct the date as UTC date, then you will get rid off the timezone shifts.

`var dt=new Date(Date.UTC(yyyy, mm, dd))`

Where yyyy is year, mm is zero based month and dd is day...

Comment: In other words: They describe the same _instant_, just in different time zones.

Answer (score 0):

Web API was converting it so I founded a solution from internet after lot of research
modify startup.cs file as

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
 });
```

create a new class and paste the following lines

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Converter.shared
{
  public class DateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
        {
            public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
            {
                return DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString());
            }

            public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
            {
                writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"));
            }
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add on @Pavel Gatnar's answer.

In JavaScript/Typescript, if you already have a date/datetime variable and you want to get the specific year, month and day, do this:

```
var myDate = new Date;

// somewhere else in your code
var UTCDate = new Date(Date.UTC(myDate.getFullYear(), myDate.getMonth(), myDate.getDate())) // not getDay() but getDate() :-)
```

Then, you can post `UTCDate` to your Web API, and now the dates from your Angular Web App and your Web API should be the same.

Hope this helps!